Kernel of the idele to ideal map $( \cdot ): \mathbb{I}_K \to I_K$ with restricted domain and codomain.
I'm a little confused about this step that is made in a proof I'm attempting to understand. For some notation, we have $\mathbb{I}_K$ to be the ideles of $K$, $I_K$ to be the fractional ideals of $K$, and $P_K$ to be the principal ideals of $K$ (so that $I_K / P_K$ is the ideal class group). We similarly have $I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ and $P_K(\mathfrak{m})$ are the ideals (and principal ideals respectively) that are coprime to some modulus $\mathfrak{m}$, and $\mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) = \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{I}_K \mid \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod{\mathfrak{m}} \}$.
We have the map $( \cdot ): \mathbb{I}_K \to I_K$ defined by
$$\alpha = (\alpha_{\mathfrak{p}})_\mathfrak{p} \mapsto \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \nmid \infty} \mathfrak{p}^{v_\mathfrak{p}(\alpha_\mathfrak{p})},$$
and we restrict it to the domain $\mathbb{I}^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle} = \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{I}_K \mid \alpha_\mathfrak{p} = 1 \text{ for all } \mathfrak{p} \mid \mathfrak{m} \}$. We then claim the homomorphism
$$\mathbb{I}^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle} \to I_K(\mathfrak{m}) / P_K(\mathfrak{m}), \quad \alpha \mapsto (\alpha) \pmod{P_K(\mathfrak{m})}.$$
Two things are stated about this map. Firstly, that it is surjective, and secondly, that the kernel is $(\mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) \cdot K^\times) \cap \mathbb{I}^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle}$. I am okay with surjectivity, but I cannot work out the kernel.
I've tried that if $\alpha \in \ker( (\cdot) )$, this is equivalent to $(\alpha) = x\mathcal{O}_K = \prod_{ \substack{\mathfrak{p} \nmid \infty \\ \mathfrak{p} \nmid \mathfrak{m} }} \mathfrak{p}^{v_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)}$ for some $x \in K$, so we have $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{p}) = v_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ for all $\mathfrak{p} \nmid \infty, \mathfrak{m}$ and $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{p}) = 0$ for all $\mathfrak{p} \mid \mathfrak{m}$. However, I don't know what to do from here to get it into the required form. I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I can't tell.
